# Show alert with positive and negative button from service without using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Tags: android, android-service

I want to show notification as an alert dialog with Approve and Decline buttons o it when the application is in the foreground. However, when I use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, the positive and negative buttons aren't working. And also normal alert dialogs having context issues.

So, how to show alert dialogs from service without using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the right answer is to not do it. Use a `Notification`, perhaps a high-priority one, so that it shows in heads-up mode on Android 5.0+. This allows the user to interact with the `Notification` when it appears if the user wants to, but otherwise it just rolls into the status bar as normal.

Bear in mind that you do not know what the user is doing with their device when you want to display this alert, and the user may not appreciate you interrupting them in the middle of playing a game, using a navigation app while driving, etc.

There are *very* few cases where users will agree that taking over the foreground from the background is a good idea (e.g., incoming phone call). In those cases, use a dialog-themed `Activity` (i.e., one whose theme extends from one with `Dialog` in its name, such as `Theme.Material.Dialog`).